# Story about two men and a supercomputer with all answers

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, computers

I am looking for a short story where 2 men (very old and young) looking for a planet with supercomputer, who knows answers for all questions. Finally, they find it. But computer is not giving straight answers, as they don't know to ask proper questions. Old man dies at the end. Point is, to ask proper question, one needs to know at least half of the answer.

Comment: This is a pretty good first question. (At least, I take it to be a first.) But do you know when you might have read this, or where you found it? Any reason guess and other additional information would help. Thanks!

Comment: I read it long time ago, 1980-is. I remember last bit, where supercomputer is asking himself questions, proper questions, and giving answers to them,

Comment: Found it, Ask a Foolish Question by R. Sheckley

Comment: I was already writing my answer when you posted your comment that you'd found it. If you don't mind, I will finish writing my answer, so it will be there the next time somebody's looking for that story.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You may be interested in reading [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/31394) on how to write a good story-ID question :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Not that this wasn't a good question.

Comment: @user14111 I didn't say it wasn't, but a bit of extra advice never hurts.

Comment: You spelled story wrong in the title, and there is no period, but other then that its ok

Comment: And here I was thinking the answer was 42...

Comment: The story doesn't specifically call it a supercomputer.

Comment: I'd say "insufficient data for meaningful answer", but that's a different story with a sequence of pairs of people talking to successively more powerful computers...

Comment: @sluger You spelled "than" wrong in your comment.

Answer (score 25):

**I am looking for a short story**

["Ask a Foolish Question"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58542) by [Robert Sheckley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sheckley). You can read it at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33854) or listen to a reading at [Librivox](http://ia802701.us.archive.org/9/items/short_scifi_042_1011_librivox/ssf042_askafoolishquestion_sheckley_wt.mp3).

**where 2 men (very old and young) looking for a planet with supercomputer, who knows answers for all questions.**

> "We'll find out," Morran murmured. He helped the old man unstrap himself. "We're going to find the Answerer!"
>
> Lingman nodded at his young partner. They had been reassuring themselves for years. Originally it had been Lingman's project. Then Morran, graduating from Cal Tech, had joined him. Together they had traced the rumors across the solar system. The legends of an ancient humanoid race who had known the answer to all things, and who had built Answerer and departed.

**Finally, they find it. But computer is not giving straight answers, as they don't know to ask proper questions.**

> "Is the universe expanding?" Morran asked confidently.
>
> "'Expansion' is a term inapplicable to the situation. Universe, as the Questioner views it, is an illusory concept."
>
> "Can you tell us *anything?*" Morran asked.
>
> "I can answer any valid question concerning the nature of things."

**Old man dies at the end.**

> "Shall we go, sir?" Morran asked. Lingman's eyes remained closed. His taloned fingers were clenched, his cheeks sunk further in. The skull was emerging.

**Point is, to ask proper question, one needs to know at least half of the answer.**

Yes, that's the last line of the story:

> In order to ask a question you must already know most of the answer.